# Looking for specific string pattern in java

Tags: java

I have a requirement where by I have to add some string pattern into a collection only if it is not present and I need to look out for exact pattern.

For ex, assuming against a given key, value is abc,bcd,aefg and the new pattern to be added is efg then it should be added (assuming values are separated by comma as delimiter)

I was planning to use `StringBuffer.indexOf(String Str)` method but am not using it because it will return the index, if the pattern to look for occurs as a substring in the value (in the above case efg already occurs as a substring).
I know that there is some solution using Regex feature of Java 5 but I need to brushup on that topic a bit.
As of now, I am doing the following

1. Iterate through the values which I get against a key (value list separated by delimeter)
2. do an exact match for the new pattern (to be added) and add it only if its absent.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Split it by a delimiter and add them to a Set.

Comment: Ummmm use `Collection.contains()`?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood you the contains method should do the trick?

str1.toLowerCase().contains(",efg,")

Comment: This will not work as if the efg is at the start or end of the string it will probably not have the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a set?

```
String[] strings = myString.split(",");
Set<String> set;
//add strings to set
```

If not:

```
String[] strings = myString.split(",");
List<String> list;
for (String s : strings) {
   if(!list.contains(s)) {
       list.add(s);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The collection interface itself has a contains method.  If you are looking to only add if the collection does not already contain the exact string then you could use that and save your self from iterating over the contents.  The collections contains method will use the "equals" method for it's contents:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Collection method is not working (I have to put some kind of iterator logic).. because I have a map and I need to append some value against a key only if the value is not already a part of existing value against that key

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
@Test
public void addString() {
    String target = "abc,bcd,aefg";
    String stringToAdd = "efg";

    System.out.println(target);

    if(! new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(target.split(","))).contains(stringToAdd)) {
        target += "," + stringToAdd;
    }
    System.out.println(target);

    if(! new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(target.split(","))).contains(stringToAdd)) {
        target += "," + stringToAdd;
    }
    System.out.println(target);
}
```

**Output**

```
abc,bcd,aefg
abc,bcd,aefg,efg
abc,bcd,aefg,efg
```

The code proceeds as follow:

1. [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) using by `,`
2. make a set of the resulting array by [converting the array to a list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) and feeding it to [HasSet's contructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet%28java.util.Collection%29)
3. use Set's method [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) to check whether the string to add is present
4. add if not present

**EDIT**

You could try using this regex `^efg|^efg,.+|.+,efg,.+|.+,efg$`:

```
@Test
public void addStringRegEx() {
    String target = "abc,bcd,aefg";
    String stringToAdd = "efg";

    String regex =
            // string is alone at first position and there is no comma
            "^" + stringToAdd + 
            "|" +  // OR
            // string is first and is followed by a comma and some other strings
            "^" + stringToAdd + ",.+" +   
            "|" +   // OR
            // string is enclosed within two commas i.e. in the middle
            ".+," + stringToAdd + ",.+" +
            "|" +   // OR
            // string is at the end and there are some strings and comma before it
            ".+," + stringToAdd + "$";

    Assert.assertFalse("aefg".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertFalse(",efg".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertFalse("efg,".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertFalse(",efg,".matches(regex));

    Assert.assertTrue("efg".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertTrue("foo,efg".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertTrue("foo,efg,bar".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertTrue("efg,bar".matches(regex));


    if(! target.matches(regex)) {
        target += "," + stringToAdd;
    }
    Assert.assertEquals("abc,bcd,aefg,efg", target);

    if(! target.matches(regex)) {
        target += "," + stringToAdd;
    }
    Assert.assertEquals("abc,bcd,aefg,efg", target);
}
```

Comment: Well I have actually coded something similar. I was trying to see if there is some other way.. will try to dig in Regex to see if there is some alternate solution.

Comment: @user1588737 check my edit for a check using regex, hope it does meet your needs.